# calculate a cumulative sum (cumsum) over an xmlpath in an xmltable

Tags: postgresql, xpath

I want to calculate the cumulative page height of an xml table. This seems to be easy as `preceding-sibling` is returning all siblings and we just need to sum it up. However the following query fails with

> SQL Error [XX000]: ERROR: unexpected XPath object type 3

```
SELECT array_length(regexp_split_to_array(xmltable.txt, E'\\s+'), 1) as word_count,
       xmltable.txt ~ '^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$' as is_number,
       xmltable.*
  FROM (
          select xml('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                      <content version="2.0" extractor="pdftohtml">
                        <page number="1" height="1263" width="892">
                          <text_block top="80" left="137" width="255" height="159">
                            <text top="85" left="197" font="DDUBPN+GlyphLessFont" size="14">Foo</text>
                            <text top="105" left="142" font="DDUBPN+GlyphLessFont" size="23">Bar</text>
                          </text_block>
                        </page>
                        <page number="2" height="1263" width="892">
                          <text_block top="80" left="137" width="255" height="159">
                            <text top="85" left="197" font="DDUBPN+GlyphLessFont" size="14">Foo</text>
                            <text top="105" left="142" font="DDUBPN+GlyphLessFont" size="23">Bar</text>
                          </text_block>
                        </page>
                      </content>') as report
        ) as t,
       XMLTABLE('//text'
                PASSING report
                COLUMNS ordinality FOR ORDINALITY,
                        x int PATH '@top',
                        y int path '@left',
                        page int path '../../@number',
                        page_hight int path '../../@height',
                        txt varchar path 'text()[1]',
                        cumsum_page_height int path 'sum(../../preceding-sibling::page/@height)'
       );
```

I don't understand the error, I can easily do `SELECT xpath('sum(/a/value/@h)', '<a><value h="12"/><value h="13"/></a>'::xml);`

Are xpath functions not supported in `XMLTABLE`? How should I work around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like PostgreSQL cannot handle other XPath data type besides node-set or string. Use XPath `string()` to convert boolean and number data type expressions.

This SQL expression:

```
SELECT array_length(regexp_split_to_array(xmltable.txt, E'\\s+'), 1) as word_count,
       xmltable.txt ~ '^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$' as is_number,
       xmltable.*
  FROM (
          select xml('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
                      <content version="2.0" extractor="pdftohtml">
                        <page number="1" height="1263" width="892">
                          <text_block top="80" left="137" width="255" height="159">
                            <text top="85" 
                                  left="197"
                                  font="DDUBPN+GlyphLessFont"
                                  size="14">Foo</text>
                            <text top="105"left="142"
                                  font="DDUBPN+GlyphLessFont"
                                  size="23">Bar</text>
                          </text_block>
                        </page>
                        <page number="2" height="1263" width="892">
                          <text_block top="80" left="137" width="255" height="159">
                            <text top="85" 
                                  left="197" 
                                  font="DDUBPN+GlyphLessFont"
                                  size="14">Foo</text>
                            <text top="105" 
                                  left="142" 
                                  font="DDUBPN+GlyphLessFont" 
                                  size="23">Bar</text>
                          </text_block>
                        </page>
                      </content>') as report
        ) as t,
       XMLTABLE('//text'
                PASSING report
                COLUMNS ordinality FOR ORDINALITY,
                        x int PATH '@top',
                        y int path '@left',
                        page int path '../../@number',
                        page_hight int path '../../@height',
                        txt varchar path 'normalize-space()',
                        cumsum_page_height int path 
                            'string(sum(../../preceding-sibling::page/@height))'
       );
```

Output:

```
| word_count | is_number | ordinality | x   | y   | page | page_hight | txt | cumsum_page_height |
| ---------- | --------- | ---------- | --- | --- | ---- | ---------- | --- | ------------------ |
| 1          | false     | 1          | 85  | 197 | 1    | 1263       | Foo | 0                  |
| 1          | false     | 2          | 105 | 142 | 1    | 1263       | Bar | 0                  |
| 1          | false     | 3          | 85  | 197 | 2    | 1263       | Foo | 1263               |
| 1          | false     | 4          | 105 | 142 | 2    | 1263       | Bar | 1263               |
```

---

[Check it on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pSG1GJ2sXpkEP38cmaJkx2/0)